# Chat event time warp

Tags: feature-request, chat

This is what I see on the main page of Physics.SE right now:

[image]

This is what I see [in the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar):

[image]

This is what I see under ["schedule events"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar?tab=schedule):

[image]

My system clock is 21:19 PM, on Ubuntu.

<s>Unless I've managed to create a time warp (yay me!), I'm guessing this isn't supposed to happen ;-)</s>

Apparently this is intentional, so people come on time. I don't really see the need for this (see comments below)

Comment: And, I was the one who saw it - an *evidence* though ;-)

Comment: Retagging this as a feature request, since this is intentional and has been this way for two years.

Comment: You could have fixed this yourself with [just a jump to the left, and then a jump to the right](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rtkdo7bOmJc). I'm just _sayin'_.

Comment: @balpha: Hm? What do you mean by that? How is `'Just now'=='in 12 mins'` intentional? (I don't mind `12==9`, that may have been due to the gap in time between taking screenshots)

Comment: In the same way that the Bon Jovi concert starts at 8, even though they don't even play until 9:15. I'm not even disagreeing with you; I've never been quite happy with the phrasing myself. But it was deliberately chosen to get people to be there on time.

Comment: @balpha: Ah, makes sense. I agree, though it might be less confusing to the participants of the event if it said "in 12 mins" on the front page as well. Not sure though -- as you say, that may encourage folks to come late.

Comment: Folks joining a chatroom is fairly unintrusive (unlike someone trying to find their way to their seat at a concert), so this is probably safe to fix up. (cc @balpha)

Comment: @AnnaLear: Of course, we have a few "what fresh hell is this?" new users to chat who need a few tips. But that's rare.